# Avoid google indexing subdomains

Tags: indexing, seo, cpanel

As far as I searched for it, not able to find a proper answer for such kinda problem.

I have a few TLDs installed on the same cPanel account.
One of them is known as the main domain, and the rest are secondary domain.

cPanel automatically creates subdomains when you add a secondary domain somthing like;
http://secondary.maindomain.com

My problem is google indexed my pages both from 2 addresses.

Like:

secondary.com/blabla.html

secondary.maindomain.com/blabla.html

How can I remove those indexes from google? And
How can I avoid those subdomains being indexed for the future?

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you can add robots.txt to your document root path and add 'Disallow: ' to avoid any search engine or Google to index your files or directories.

For example to avoid indexing your subdomain in google add below entries in robots.txt and place robots.txt in document root path of you subdomain:

> User-agent: Googlebot
>
> Disallow: /

or for all search engines:

> User-agent: *
>
> Disallow: /